# JDBC calculate the average

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

It is my database table called Cruise_Serial:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4n16.png)

I want to get each cruiseID's total average evaluation number, for example:

for cruiseID 4013, it has to be: (5+5+4+4+3+4+4+5+4+4+4+4)/12
here is what I write for the PreparedStatement:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connect1.prepareStatement("SELECT CRUISE_SERIAL＿NUMBER, AVG(CRUISE_SERIAL.EVALUATION_FOOD, CRUISE_SERIAL.EVALUATION_SEHEDULE, CRUISE_SERIAL.EVALUATIONA_COMFORTABLE,CRUISE_SERIAL.EVALUATION_TIDY),AVG(CRUISE_SERIAL_NUMBER) "
          + "FROM CRUISE_SERIAL GROUP by CRUISE_SERIAL_NUMBER");
```

But the error shows in this line of my code, please help me how to fix it. Thanks!!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Lexical error at line 1, column 21.  Encountered: "\uff3f" (65343), after : "".
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at lab.User_Cruise.cruiseEvaluation
```

Comment: I remove it, but the result is same :(

Comment: `avg()` doesn't work that way. It's an aggregate function that takes a **single** column as its input and calculates the average across different rows, not columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your underscores aren't regular ones, see the second one here :

```
CRUISE_SERIAL＿NUMBER
```

As the error tells you, this *large* underscore is unicode character U+FF3F, which is

> [FULLWIDTH LOW LINE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff3f/index.htm)

Just replace it with a regular underscore.

Comment: Oh! I correct the underscore line, but it still has some error says: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "," at line 1, column 63.
 at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
 at lab.User_Cruise.cruiseEvaluation

Comment: For the second error I don't think you can call `AVG` on more than one column. Try `AVG(a), AVG(b)` instead of `AVG(a,b)` or (maybe `AVG(a+b/2)` if that is what you want).